# What build args to use to automatically update UWP app every hour

Tags: uwp, msbuild, auto-update

I'm trying to configure my UWP app to update automatically every hour, even if the app was not restarted.

Here's the build task from my pipeline:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    platform: 'x86'
    solution: 'stuff/something/MyKioskApp.csproj'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="x86"
                  /p:AppxPackageDir="$(appxPackageDir)"
                  /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=SideloadOnly
                  /p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=true
                  /p:PackageCertificateThumbprint="$(thumbprint)" 
                  /p:PackageCertificateKeyFile="$(signingCert.secureFilePath)"
                  /p:PackageCertificatePassword="$(certPassword)"
                  /p:AppxBundle=Always
                  /p:GenerateAppInstallerFile=true
                  /p:AppInstallerUri="$(InstallerLocation)" 
                  /p:AppInstallerUpdateFrequency=1 
                  /p:AppInstallerCheckForUpdateFrequency=OnApplicationRun'
```

Currently the app occasionally updates to the latest version after a reboot, but not always.

I'm having trouble finding which msbuildargs and parameters I should use to make it check for updates more frequently. There doesn't seem to be a list of them anywhere that I can find.

All the examples I can find online have `/p:AppInstallerCheckForUpdateFrequency=OnApplicationRun'`

If it makes any difference, the app is designed to run in Assigned Access mode on a windows 10 machine, and may not be rebooted regularly.

Comment: Can you tell us why are you trying to do that? Update the app every hour is a very strange behavior.

Comment: I'd like to have more control over when it updates than "whenever the stakeholders decide to reboot". Do you have an answer to my question?

Comment: Usually UWP is updated after restarting, only the game will be updated dynamically. In addition, About this, I need to ask other engineers for advice.

Comment: When build the package, you can specify how often the app checks for updates. About how to specify, you can refer to this [document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/03/22/handling-auto-updates-for-sideloaded-uwp-and-desktop-bridge-apps/). In addition, a list of properties for the AppInstallerCheckForUpdateFrequency build switch currently are not published. This should be set via the UI as outlined from the link. You also need to be aware that checking for updates isn’t the same thing as actually updating the app. The app must be restarted before any updates will be applied.